# What is the difference between supervenience and grounding?

Tags: metaphysics, analytic-philosophy

What is the difference between supervenience and grounding?

Both amount to the claim that there is nothing over and above them in the sense that the grounded adds nothing to being but the grounding and that the supervening does not add anything to being but that which it supervenes upon. There are some conditions like reflexivity that grounding does not satisfy, but other than that, what is the difference between them?

Thanks in advance!